# Angular Interceptor URL not being updated with new URL, appeneds to original

Tags: angular, http, interceptor

Hi so I am new to interceptors, and I wanted to redirect SOME requests to a different domain more or less because the port access is different. But I can't get the interceptor to work, here is my code for the interceptor :

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log("initial request: ", req)
    const url = '10.0.0.211:8080/Vanta/exports/';
    req = req.clone({
      url: url + req.url
    });
    console.log("Dupe Req: ", req.url)
    return next.handle(req);
}
```

now the const URL is static here for use case but it would be pulling from the address bar initially,

here is the output of this:
[image]
so the Dupe Req has the correct url, but in the get command localhost (or whatever the original url is, ie: if is start with 10.0.0.211 it becomes
[http://10.0.0.211/10.0.0.211:8080/Vanta/exports/chemistry-800133-2021-09-22-08-43-56.csv"](http://10.0.0.211/10.0.0.211:8080/Vanta/exports/chemistry-800133-2021-09-22-08-43-56.csv%22),
why is the URL not being overriden to  what I thought wouldve been
http://10.0.0.211:8080/Vanta/exports/chemistry-800133-2021-09-22-08-43-56.csv

Answer (score -1):

`HttpRequest` does not contain host, if You edit URL host is not modified. Your original request is `http://localhost:4200/chemistry...` and you modify only `url` part of the request.

Comment: What would be the proper way toi edit the host? at the end of the day all i want to do is change/add a port to the host prior to '/', so it would be (using the url and not localhost) ```http://10.0.0.211**:8080**/vanta/exp...

Comment: How do You execute http call ? Do You have some proxy configured ?

Comment: Um I do not:                                    
this.http.get(filename,{ responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe ....                                                                                   
 it was what i thought going to be a simple file download from another port

Comment: Also may I add that the URL before the port number is dynamic...

Comment: Simplest way to achieve Your goal will be to create new HttpRequest instead of cloning it `const httpRequest = new HttpRequest(req.method, 'http://10.0.0.211:8080/Vanta/exports/chemistry-800133-2021-09-22-08-43-56.csv');`

Comment: If it's dynamic You should change url only without host and setup proxy.